# Strip HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, im having a lil problem here.

I created a button and when you click, it will copy content from DIV into textarea. My problem is, i want to Strip down the HTML tags .

I just want it to be  `https://pbs.....jpg` without the img src and all.

Thank you (my first time using SOF)

Please view my fiddle
[my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/netleie/panuraqx/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/panuraqx/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the src of the img, then use this:
https://jsfiddle.net/panuraqx/21/

```
$target.attr('src');
```

If you want the html without the tags use this:
https://jsfiddle.net/panuraqx/22/

```
$target.text();
```

Btw I cleaned your fiddle a lil bit